# Typewriter effect only with SCSS (width animation)

Tags: html, css, animation, sass, flexbox

I am developing a typewritter effect with SCSS, [here is the Codepen](https://codepen.io/fbuireu/pen/GQMdQm/). To achieve the effect, I animate the `width`, to `0` to `30rem`. I am trying to achieve a more modular workaround, which works in any desired width, no matter the width of the content.

For the moment, I have been only to think with a kind of `@mixin` which get the `width` (or `max-width`) value of the content, but it's not what I am looking for.

I have also tried with a `flex` container and `flex-grow` content but I had no luck.

How can achieve this? I am also looking for a way to improve and refactor my code, so I am open to any advice that you could give me.

Here is the snippet (this is CSS, not SCSS as my pen shows):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro);
body {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace; }
  body .typewriter-text {
    margin: 4rem auto 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    width: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); }

.line-1 {
  animation: blink 1s step-end 7 backwards, type 2s 2s steps(30, end) forwards, blink 1s 3.6s step-end 7, remove-blink 1s 6.3s step-end forwards; }

.line-2 {
  animation: remove-blink 0s 0s step-end forwards, type 3s 7.5s steps(40, end) forwards, remove-blink 0s 10.5s forwards; }

.line-3 {
  animation: remove-blink 0s 0s step-end forwards, type 3s 10.5s steps(40, end) forwards, blink 1s 14s infinite alternate; }

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); }
  100% {
    width: 20rem;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); } }

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent; } }

@keyframes remove-blink {
  to {
    border-color: transparent; } }
```

```html
<div class="typewritter-wrapper">
  <h1 class="typewriter-text line-1">Lorem Ipsum D</h1>
  <p class="typewriter-text line-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit.</p>
  <p class="typewriter-text line-3">Donec vitae est commodo, imperdiet nulla at.</p>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS doesn't have a method to calculate and adjust one element according to another, which would be needed here.

What one can do though, is to use `transform`, where one *cover* the text with a pseudo and then move the text element to the left and the pseudo to the right, revealing the text.

The downside, not being able to calculate width's, is that with wider content it will go faster and narrower slower, and the only reasonable way to solve that is to either calculate the text length server side and set the steps/duration using inline style, or client side using a script.

*Note, in below sample I removed the "blinking" effect to simplify the code.*

Stack snippet

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro);
body {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
}

.typewriter-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.typewriter-text {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.typewriter-text::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.line-1 {
  animation: type 2s 0.5s steps(30, end) forwards;
}

.line-1::after {
  animation: type2 2s 0.5s steps(30, end) forwards;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@keyframes type2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(100% - 1px));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter-wrapper">
  <h1 class="typewriter-text line-1">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="typewriter-wrapper">
  <p class="typewriter-text line-1">Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
```

---

Updated.

I also [found a solution at CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/) using width, cleverly combined with Flexbox, though the *typing faster/slower for short/long text* issue applies here too.

Stack snippet

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro);
body {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
}

.typewriter-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typewriter-text {
  position: relative;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.line-1 {
  animation: type 3s 0.5s steps(30, end) forwards,
  blink .5s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes type {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes blink {
  0%,
  100% {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: white
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter-wrapper">
  <div>
    <h1 class="typewriter-text line-1">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="typewriter-wrapper">
  <div>
    <p class="typewriter-text line-1">Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect! That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I need to change the HTML structure, which make sense to add the flexbox power.